# Can Android apps communicate with WP7 ones?

Tags: android, windows-phone-7

I was wondering if it's possible to make an app on android communicate with one on Windows Phone 7, or if there's even a way to develop apps for both platforms in the same language.

Comment: No we can develop an app using same language. but app same for each platform in their language that communicate through bluetooth or wifi is possible.but very complicated.. i dont if its really possible or not.

Comment: Your question is overly broad. What kind of communication are you interested in?

Comment: Mostly game related data communication. Imagine pong as a simple example, when the ball goes off the top of one player's screen, data containing the position, speed and direction will be sent to the other device.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way would likely be communicating via a web server to pass the data too and from each device. It depends on what you intend to pass between them though.

Answer (score 2):

Network sockets will allow communication between ANY devices.

Comment: Except you can't create a socket in the current version of WP7.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to share some(!) code of the business layer logic.

There is a mono framework for android and iphone. You can use it to write code in C# for both devices.

However, the UI is device-dependent, so that cannot be shared.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of quick and dirty ways now to develop apps for cross-platform is to use a mini-browser windows that simply points to a URL with no toolbars such as m.example.com.

Developing your "app" site in HTML5 allows a lot of possibilities to open up as far as what you can do from there. This gives you the opportunity to work a lot with cross-platform databases and dynamic data as well.